# Upload PDF file to multiple folder in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload a PDF file to multiple folders, as the code which I use as below

```
$uploaddir="uploadfile";
$uploaddir1="../t1/admin/uploadfile";
$type=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
$path=$uploaddir.'/'. $_FILES['file']['name'];
$path1=$uploaddir1.'/'. $_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$path);
copy($path, $path1);
```

when executed the PDF file moved to $path (ie.uploadfile) folder but not to the folder path (ie. ../t1/admin/uploadfile)
Please any solutions.

Comment: Does the copy function return true or false? Your code doesn't check. Does the account under which PHP runs definitely have permission to the second folder? Do you get any errors/warnings from PHP? Are errors/warnings enabled in PHP?

Comment: If I have changed move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$path1) then it is moved to the $path1 folder and error is not enabled.

Comment: Check if you can copy straight from the tmp directory

Comment: `error is not enabled`...so please enable PHP error reporting (or if it's a live server, you should enable logging instead). It's silly to have it switched off when you're debugging.

Comment: P.S. You didn't answer if copy returns true or false?

Comment: It is working with the same code

Comment: same code as what? Your question is because it's not working ,now you're saying it's working. Or maybe you need to clarify what you mean, because it's not clear. Usually it's better to [edit] your question anyway when you have any extra information for us. Thanks